# Mini split convertion to water cooled using coaxial heat exchanger

Tags: hvac

Long story long.... I am putting a 6000 BTU split AC on my boat. It is a LG DUALCOOL with Watt Control-Eco - T06EV4, I chose it because it has 3 power settings you can control: 215, 312 or 419 watts. This makes it the only AC i could find that is reasonable to run on batteries. Point is I have bought it and I am married to using it.

Thing is the out door unit is rather large, and despite checking the measurements before I bought it, I can't get it in the space I was planning to put it. On top of that putting an AC like this on a boat is just a bad idea... the salt air will kill it for sure, and probably quite quickly.

So I got to thinking that changing the condenser loop from air cooled to liquid cooled might solve a bunch of problems. I have been looking at the commercially available marine units (they are crazy expensive!) and it seams to just be a few loops of 3/4" or 5/8" pipe, with a smaller pipe inside. So the coolant is circulated through one pipe and sea water is pumped through that other. Sounds easy enough. copper pipe, bending, soldering, all doable.

[image]

But I can't get a clear idea how long the loop needs to be. There must be a BTU to surface area to temperature hysteresis formula... but I can't find it.

I have worked out using rough measurements and estimations based on a photo that one of the best commercially available marine units that is about 6000 btu has a loop about 1.5m long. But also it uses voodoo geometry and Unobtainium pipes to create "optimised surface area to enhance heat transfer" So my bodge version wont be as efficient.

So my question is how long should it be? It can be too short, but can it be too long? Should I just make it 3m and be done with it? Copper is expensive......

Other option is to just buy this from Allyexpress. I probably can't build one that cheaply... but is it suitable?

Description:
Coaxial Tube Coils are designed for use as Water Cooled Condensers, Water Chillers and in Water Source Heat Pumps. Coaxial heat exchanger has tube-in-tube and corrupted inner tube designing. Rugged tube surface can maximize the overall heat transfer. The heat exchanger (also known as double tube HEX) consists of two concentric tubes. The cooling water flows through the inner tube while the refrigerant does it through the space between the two tubes. Tube-in-tube heat exchangers, or double-tube heat exchangers, are specially designed for heating or cooling products with low-medium viscosity. The great advantage is to be able to process products with fibers or particles, without the risk of clogging. It can achieve a pure counter current flow, which allows a temperature crossover to be achieved, so that the cold fluid can be heated above the hot fluid outlet temperature

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chance of anything not designed for a marine environment surviving in it, never mind operating in it, is generally either fat or slim

Comment: This is either the worst or the best idea I've heard of in a decade.

Comment: I guess there's not a lot to lose! I note that the two charts shown are for R22 and R134a. Your system almost certainly uses R410a, though, which operates at pressures higher than either of those (450 psi is not uncommon). I'd suggest brazing rather than soldering.

Comment: R32, so good point on pressure and brazing

Comment: R32 has similar working pressure to R410A around 12-26 Bar (174-377 Psi)  The above has a working pressure of 30 bar.  Do we think that is ok?

Comment: Plot thickens, this is not unprecedented: https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY/comments/eqog9r/mini_split_ac_unit_converted_to_use_water_for_boat/

Comment: seller says: "tube in tube heat exchanger cannot hold R410a/R32 working pressure"

Comment: After more consideration, this is a great idea.  The issue is finding the proper working material.  I will stay tuned.   Good Luck.

Comment: If saltwater corrosion is a concern with the refrigerant line in the heat exchanger, you can make that a secondary loop containing just a few liters of distilled water (+corrosion inhibitor?) and make the primary loop from a brazed plate heat exchanger, available in stainless and bronze, to keep the salt water separated from copper lines. Incredibly compact and not expensive. A second pump to be sure, but not much flow required. https://www.google.com/search?q=brazed+plate+heat+exchanger

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while interesting, it's not about _home_ improvement, but _boat_ improvement.

Comment: Boats can be homes, @FreeMan

Comment: I am unfamiliar with copper in a marin environment. I thought stainless steel was the metal to use. I  think the rest of yhe unit wont last long due to corrision. This includes electrical and electronic components.

Comment: Apologizes for boat question on this forum, i could not find any other HVAC place to post.

Comment: Salt water is not so much my issue, I can handle that part.  It is more my full understanding of HVAC.  I will make the loop myself, but 
how long should it be? It can be too short, but can it be too long?